# Run issue with Deepstream 5.1 and YOLOv4

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia, tensorrt, yolov4

Complete information of setup.

**• Hardware Platform (Jetson / GPU)** : GPU
**• CUDA** : 11.1
**• DeepStream Version** : 5.1
**• JetPack Version (valid for Jetson only)**: None
**• TensorRT Version** : 7.2.3.4
**• NVIDIA GPU Driver Version (valid for GPU only)** : 460.84

I have done Deepstream 5.1 setup and while [Run the Sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/yolov4_deepstream/blob/master/deepstream_yolov4/README.md#5-run-the-sample) getting below error.
Can anybody help me around?

ERROR:
............

(deepstreamer_env) xxxx@xxxx:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.1/sources/deepstream_yolov4$ deepstream-app -c deepstream_app_config_yoloV4.txt
Unknown or legacy key specified 'is-classifier' for group [property]
** ERROR: main:655: Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED
Quitting
ERROR from sink_sub_bin_sink1: Could not open file "yolov4.mp4" for writing.
Debug info: gstfilesink.c(431): gst_file_sink_open_file (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstBin:processing_bin_0/GstBin:sink_bin/GstBin:sink_sub_bin1/GstFileSink:sink_sub_bin_sink1:
system error: Permission denied
ERROR from sink_sub_bin_sink1: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.
Debug info: gstbasesink.c(5265): gst_base_sink_change_state (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstBin:processing_bin_0/GstBin:sink_bin/GstBin:sink_sub_bin1/GstFileSink:sink_sub_bin_sink1:
Failed to start
App run failed

#deepstream #tensorrt #yolov4

Comment: I got a solution.

I create a new file as yolov4.mp4 then gave read & write permission then it works me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that deepstream can not write into the specified directory because of permission issue. You may first check if your user has write permission to that directory or run the app with `sudo`.